# Have divs "tight fit"

Tags: html, css

This is the structure of my HTML:

```
<div> <span>Some text</span> <br/> <span>Not much text</span> </div>
<div> <span>Some text</span> <br/> <span>Not much text</span> </div>
<div> <span>Some text</span> <br/> <span>Not much text</span> </div>
```

I have three `div`s all of which contain 2 `span`s with not much text. I want all three `div`s to appear on the same line. At the moment, each `div` takes up the whole width of a new line.

I don't want to hardcode a width. I would much prefer if the `div`s behaved like `span`s in the sense the they have a "tight fit" for their content (no whitespace).

Comment: Why not use spans instead of divs if they should behave like spans? There is still the class attribute to differentiate...

Comment: You want the `<br>`s on the same line too?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Yes, how should I do that?

Comment: Then yeah, you need the divs to `float:left`, and to ensure they stay on the same line you should set widths (px or percentage).

Comment: width: fit-content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to apply `float` left to the `div` so that they sit inline. Or, you could apply `display:inline-block` to the `div`, but that would only work in IE8+.

But I have to ask the question, why do you need the `div` tag initially? it seems like you are creating more work for yourself here.

I would prefer to start with an inline element such as a `span`, then apply `display:inline-block` for padding, margin's if needed.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why everyone is saying `float:left` or `display:inline-block;` when you said you wanted the div to behave like a span. The correct way to do that is this:

```
div {
    display: inline;
}
```

#### Ignore anyone saying this:

> "If you want it to *look* like a span, use a span tag"

It's not true and that's what CSS is for - describing what content should *look like*, HTML is for describing what the content *is*.

I'm sure you have your reasons for choice of tags, and there are probably better ones to choose but it's impossible to say without any actual context. However `<div>` and `<span>` have no actual semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1):

DIVs, by default, behave as "block level" elements. Block-level elements typically contain inline elements and other block-level elements. When rendered visually, block-level elements usually begin on a new line.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As there are [plenty of tags to choose from](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/), a rule of thumb that I go by is to say if you require an element that behaves like another element, there is probably a more appropriate choice of element to be made.

Comment: Your "rule of thumb" defeats much of the purpose of CSS and HTML. You don't choose elements based on what you want them to look like, but based on context (what it means in the document). If you want an `<h1>` to `float:left` or appear inline, you don't change the tag, you change the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want,

```
    <div style="float:left;padding:2px;"> <span>Some text</span> <br/> <span>Not much text</span> </div>
    <div style="float:left;padding:2px;"> <span>Some text more text</span> <br/> <span>Not much text</span> </div>
    <div style="float:left;padding:2px;"> <span>Some text more more and more text</span> <br/> <span>Not much text</span> </div>
```

Ignore padding, It's just to have better view.